# AdonisJS - Lucid ORM Computed Properties undefined

Tags: typescript, adonis.js, lucid

I'm new in AdonisJS. I want to create a simple fullname property using computed properties. But the only fullname value i get is *undefined*. I'm doing something wrong? I came from Laravel :(
Thanks!

## model

```
...
// COLUMNS
@column({ isPrimary: true })
public id: number

@column()
public firstname: string

@column()
public lastname: string

// COMPUTED PROPERTIES
static get computed () {
  return ['fullname']
}

getFullname () {
  return `${this.firstname} ${this.lastname}`;
}
// also used as (https://legacy.adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/database-getters-setters)
// getFullname ({ firstname, lastname }) {
//    return `${firstname} ${lastname}`
//}
...
```

## controller

```
...
const user = await User.find(1)
const data = {
  id: user?.id,
  fullname: user?.fullname
}
return data
...
```

## response

```
{
  "id": 1
}
```